# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 208: invalid start byte Operation failed with exitcode 1 error when importing .sql file into mysql

Tags: mysql

Creating schema steedfast

```
13:00:15 Restoring C:\Users\91907\Documents\steadfast2\steadfast2.sql
Running: mysql.exe --defaults-file="C:\Users\91907\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp670ogdrw.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments --database=steedfast  < "C:\\Users\\91907\\Documents\\steadfast2\\steadfast2.sql"
Error executing task: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 208: invalid start byte
Operation failed with exitcode 1
Error executing task local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
13:00:16 Import of C:\Users\91907\Documents\steadfast2\steadfast2.sql has finished
```

showing this error when importing data backup in
mysql workbench

Comment: Well, perhaps the file was not saved with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Show us several characters right before the FF, preferably in hex.